# How to get other fields along with the term aggregation in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.3. I want to use count a field and then group by another field. On top of this, I wish to get the other fields in that document also.

```
"aggs" : {
  "people" : {
    "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
    "aggs" : {
      "event_count" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "event" } }
    }
  }
}
```

The above ES query is equivalent to `SELECT COUNT(event) FROM table GROUP BY name;`. The new ES query should be like this SQL query: `SELECT name, address, age, COUNT(event) FROM table GROUP BY name;`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is by using the `top_hits` aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "plans": {
      "people": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [ "address", "age" ]
          }
        },
        "event_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "event"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need to realize that in your SQL query you should also group by `age` and `address` otherwise you will "miss" some of their values if you only group by `name`. Try it out and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check out the difference. All I require are the fields grouped by `name`, the values of the rest of the fields and the count of `event`. The values of the rest of the fields will not be changing per `name` so I don't think there will be any data loss.

Comment: So two people with the same name will necessarily have the same age and address?

Comment: The field is actually a unique session id. I just used name for brevity.

Comment: So it should be `"top_hits": { "size":1, "_source": [ "address", "age" ] }`